# What is the account for Pepper Host/Chat?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, pepper

I'm trying to deploy a Dialogflow chatbot on our Pepper robot. To do this, according to the tutorial provided by Softbank, I need to access to the Pepper Host and Peppy Chat CMS website to pair my chatbot and my robot. However, I have no idea what the account is. I can only see a window asking for an account and a password when opening the website, but cannot find a place where I can create an account. Dose anyone know where I can get an account? I'm in Europe by the way.

Here’s the link 
for the tutorial: https://softbankroboticstraining.github.io/pepper-chatbot-api/
for Pepper Chat:  https://pepper-chat.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the same situation a year ago and got in touch with softbank.

This is a product from SBRA (Softbank Robotics America) and you need to buy a $5000 licence.

They also wrote:

> [...] but it should be noted that we are actually no longer actively
>   developing the Pepper Chat solution (despite its overwhelming success
>   in the market!), as we are planning to launch a new 1st party solution
>   to replace it in the near future. The new solution also integrates
>   with Dialogflow, but in an abstracted, template-based way, configured
>   through the CMS.  If you are interested in purchasing a license to the
>   software, please contact our sales team at
>   sales_us@softbankrobotics.com [...]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more recent tutorial: https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-qisdk/lessons/integrating-chatbot-dialogflow

This one doesn't require any special account (apart from a dialogflow account), but does require a Pepper with the latest software.